# Android viewpager automatic sliding

Tags: android, android-viewpager

How to handle automatic swiping of viewpager pages  together with manual swipe 
i.e a set of 10 pages are there in viewpager each slides after 3 seconds but problem is when user swipes the page it moves back to sequence page what i need is following.
1>if user swipes two consecutive pages than it should not go back.
2>timer should paused when user is swiping the pages and timer should restart from screen holding the page. the code is as

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ten);
        timer = new Timer();


viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);

        // Timer for auto sliding

        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (count <= alQuestion.size()) {
                            viewPager.setCurrentItem(count, true);
                            count++;
                        } else {
                            viewPager.setCurrentItem(count);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 500, 3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently faced the same problem, and got solved by writing below function.

```
public void autoSlider(final ViewPager viewPager) {

    rr = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            int pos = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
            if(pos > i && pos != slidingImages.length - 1){
                i = pos;
                i++;
                        }
            else if(pos < (i-1)){
                i = pos;
                i++;
            }
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(i, true);
            i++;
            if (i >= slidingImages.length)
                i = 0;
            autoSlider(viewPager);
        }};
    handler.postDelayed(rr, 3000);
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

create TimerTask  class and schedule it in Timer class

```
    private class SliderTimer extends TimerTask {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        SliderActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() < color.size() - 1) {
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1);
                } else {
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}


Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new SliderTimer(), 4000, 6000)
```

Kindly follow this link for step bye step guideline https://medium.com/@shaktisinh/auto-slider-with-indicator-in-android-a28153d42125