# How to get scrolling banner in Android?

Tags: android

Does anyone know how to achieve something along the lines of this?

The bottom part of Tinder's advertisement

1) Stand out with super likes
2) Swipe around the world
3) ...

(note that unlike a view pager, it does not need to have any user interaction, all I need is a constant scrolling banner in my APP that displays various messages at the bottom of the screen)

I was thinking maybe a view pager that has a service attached to it that constantly switches between pages, but that doesn't seem quite right... Anyone else have any ideas or pointers?

[image]

Comment: No need for a `Service`.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17167740/android-viewpager-automatically-change-page
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38472916/how-to-swipe-viewpager-images-automatically-using-timetask
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17610085/how-to-switch-automatically-between-viewpager-pages https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28647370/android-viewpager-automatic-sliding

Comment: Hey, I have already answered this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38472916/how-to-swipe-viewpager-images-automatically-using-timetask/38473303?noredirect=1#comment89071939_38473303